# Odoo: ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self)

Tags: odoo, valueerror, raiseerror

I'm modifying Odoo OpenEduCat exam module to fit the need of my institution. For that, I have tailored the code as shown below. However,when I click on generate button, odoo raises expected singleton error. [Generating button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfXWJ.png)
[Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WoEG.png)

--Python code--

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class OpResultTemplate(models.Model):
    _name = 'op.result.template'
    _description = 'Result Template'
    _rec_name = 'name'

    exam_session_id = fields.Many2one(
    'op.exam.session', 'Exam Session', related='line_ids.exam_session_id', required=False)
    name = fields.Char("Name", size=254, required=True)
    result_date = fields.Date(
    'Result Date', required=True, default=fields.Date.today())
    line_ids = fields.One2many(
    'op.result.template.line', 'result_id', 'Session Lines')
####this is for semester
    inter1_ids = fields.One2many(
    'op.internal1', 'result_id', 'Internal 01')
    inter2_ids = fields.One2many(
    'op.internal2', 'result_id', 'Internal 02')
    model_ids = fields.One2many(
    'op.model', 'result_id', 'Model')
    final_ids = fields.One2many(
    'op.final', 'result_id', 'Semester')
    state = fields.Selection(
    [('normal', 'Normal'), ('semester', 'Semester')],
    string='State', required=True, default='normal')
# pass_status_ids = fields.Many2many('op.pass.status', string='Pass Status')

    @api.one
    def generate_result(self):
        data = self.read(['state'])[0]
        if data['state'] == 'normal' :
        ####Write information in to Marksheet Register the place where result generate to.
            marksheet_reg_id = self.env['op.marksheet.register'].create({
            'name': 'Mark Sheet for %s' % self.line_ids.exam_session_id.name,
            'exam_session_id': self.line_ids.exam_session_id.id,
            'generated_date': fields.Date.today(),
            'generated_by': self.env.uid,
            'status': 'draft',
            'course_id': self.line_ids.exam_session_id.course_id.name,
            'batch_id': self.line_ids.exam_session_id.batch_id.name,
            'exam_type': self.line_ids.exam_session_id.exam_type.name,
            'semester_id': self.line_ids.exam_session_id.semester_id.name,
              })
            student_list = []####Define array to store
            for exam_session in self.line_ids:####line_ids is table that located in Result generator which allow to choose exam session
                total_exam = 0.0#global var
                for exam in exam_session.exam_session_id:####exam_session.exam_lines is the table that list the exam or subject located in Result generator->Exam session
                    total_exam += exam.exam_ids.total_marks

                    for attd in exam.exam_ids.attendees_line:####exam.exam_id.attendees_line location that contant student name and mark in each subject
                        result_dict = {####this loop is to write information to result line
                        'exam_id': exam.exam_ids.id,
                        'exam_tmpl_id': exam.exam_ids.id,
                        'marks': attd.marks,####IMPORTANCE mark that student get in each subject THIS IS WHERE TO APPLY PERCENTAGES
                        'status': attd.marks >= exam.exam_ids.min_marks and####IMPORTANCE take the mark and decide pass or fail base on passing mark in each subject
                        'pass' or 'fail',
                        'per': (100 * attd.marks) / exam.exam_ids.total_marks,####NOT IMPORTANCE this can be delete, this take the mark student get and find the percentage of the subject student get in each subject
                        'student_id': attd.student_id.id,####student name
                        'total_marks': exam.exam_ids.total_marks,####the total mark of each subject that have been enter when created subject for exam
                    }
```

--Error details--

Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/v4d/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 650, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)

File "/home/v4d/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 687, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)

File "/home/v4d/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 323, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/v4d/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/v4d/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 316, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)

File "/home/v4d/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 966, in **call**
    return self.method(*args, **kw)

File "/home/v4d/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 516, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)

File "/home/v4d/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 899, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})

File "/home/v4d/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 887, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/v4d/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/v4d/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 421, in old_api
    result = new_api(recs, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/v4d/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 425, in new_api
    result = [method(rec, *args, **kwargs) for rec in self]

File "/home/v4d/odoo/addons/openeducat_exam/models/result_template.py", line 71, in generate_result
    total_exam += exam.exam_ids.total_marks

File "/home/v4d/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 821, in **get**
    record.ensure_one()

File "/home/v4d/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 5432, in ensure_one
    raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self)

ValueError: Expected singleton: op.exam(44, 45, 46)

I have tried other solutions that could be found on the Internet, but it didn't seem to work. Please kindly help me to deal with this.Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the issue in your code,

```
####IMPORTANCE take the mark and decide pass or fail base on passing mark in each subject
'status': attd.marks >= exam.exam_ids.min_marks and 'pass' or 'fail',
```

**exam.exam_ids** it will return list of browsable objects (recordset list) and you are trying to access min_marks properties, so here it gets confused  min_marks property from which object. So it raise an error.

So either you need to specify single object by specifying **exam.exam_ids[0]** (only single object will return) or you need to search proper records from the one2many model and then you can access to the min_marks field.

> Properties are separately created for all objects (OOP rule). Static
>   properties will be accessible via class.